# Store error on installing WhatsApp

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp, store, error

I have a Microsoft Lumia 640 Dual Sim, running Windows Phone 8.1. I accidentally uninstalled WhatsApp from the phone.
Now when I try to install it back from the store, i get an error asking me to try again later. The error code is `c101a7e3` . I can successfully download and install other apps.

I have tried a soft rest as well as made repeated attempts over the past 5 days, but to no avail. Is there a remedy short of a hard reset?

Comment: Are parental controls set up for your Microsoft account?

Comment: No. parental controls have never been used on the phone.

Comment: Have you visited Microsoft Care?? if not, do so.
It will help.

Comment: The best way to solve this issue is to retry later. Sadly the store has a few issues, I had stucked updates and failed installs multiple times a month. Waiting a few hour usually solves the issue usually.

Comment: Is your region and language are in accordance with each other. For example, set language to English(India) if your region is India.

Comment: @KolappanNathan, Yes it is set to English India, and aligned. As I said, I can successfully download and install any other app that I tried; both the ones that I owned and since uninstalled, and ones that had never been installed on the phone. It is only WhatsApp that throws this error. Moreover, in the details, WhatsApp last updated date is December 2015, whereas it is March 2016 in my other devices.

Comment: @Vaibhav Can u install WhatsApp on other devices linked with your MS account? Have u tried installing whatsapp on your phone using a different MS account?(In order to switch your primary account u need to reset your phone)

Comment: @KolappanNathan Actually my other device is using another account. I am reluctant to reset the phone, as I risk losing game progress etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try

1. Download via Wi-Fi and not cellular network.
2. Assure that you have the correct time and date.
3. Setting the correct time and date manually.
4. Install on phone memory instead of memory card (or vice versa).
5. Checked that your phone successfully runs its backups. If backup fails then Windows Phone can refuse to do several things, including doing update.
6. Restarting your phone after doing any of the other bullets.

Comment: 1. wifi only, not cellular. 2. checked, correct. 3. already manual 4. whatsapp does not allow installation on card, prompts install on phone memory only 5. as said, restarted multiple times.

Comment: Have you checked that your phone can successfully run backups and update? If backup fails then Windows Phone can refuse to do several things.

Answer (score -1):

Go To Settings > Storage Sense > Store New Apps on my >

Change this setting to 'Phone' if 'SD Card' is selected.

After this change, WhatsApp should install and you can change back the setting.

Comment: As Vaibhav mentioned in the reply to previous answer **Phone memory is already selected**. Please read other answers posted before attempting to answer a question. The prev answer by PChristianFrost contains the step you said.